# Rails form to create model with reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a model form that will allow me to add references by name via a `<select>` tag.

e.g.

In the database there are already RefModels with `ref_name = "a"`, `ref_name = "b"`, `ref_name = "c"`.

Form:

```
<%= form_for @model %>
  <%= f.label :ref_models, "Referenced Models:" %>
  <%= f.select :ref_models, ["a","b","c"], {}, {:multiple => true} %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @model = Model.new(model_params)
  params[:model][:ref_models].each do |ref|
    @ref = RefModel.where("ref_name = ?", ref)
    @model.ref_models << @ref
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

In my logs I'm getting this error:

```
Started POST "/models" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-25 16:20:48 -0300
Processing by ModelssController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "models"=>{..., "ref_models"=>["a", "b", "c"], ...}, "commit"=>"Create"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (RefModel(#70144007274440) expected, got String(#70144005442620)):
  app/controllers/models_controller.rb:52:in `create'
```

What's the problem?

Note:

I changed the actual model names for "model" and "ref_model" to generalize.

EDIT:
The error occurs on this line:

```
@model = Model.new(model_params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this part:

```
@model = Model.new(model_params)
```

I'm pretty sure your `model_params` is actually `params[:model]`. If yes, it means it tries to create a record for Model with the attribute `ref_models` and the values contained in `params[:model][:ref_models]`

You should take off the `params[:model][:ref_models]` before passing it to the `Model.new(params[:model])`:

```
def create
  ref_models = params[:model].delete(:ref_models)
  @model = Model.new(params[:model])
  ref_models.each do |ref|
    @ref = RefModel.where("ref_name = ?", ref)
    @model.ref_models << @ref
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do these ref_models have IDs as well as names?  If so, you can get Rails to do the heavy lifting for you.

In your view, do:

```
<%= f.select :ref_model_ids, RefModel.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

Then, you can take out the custom code from your controller, Rails knows how to link those models up appropriately.  That's assuming you have a table like model_ref_model with columns for model_id and ref_model_id.

Hope that helps...